# php - explode string at . but ignore decimal eg 2.9

Tags: php, split, explode

Currently I am exploding a string at `.` and it works as I like. the only issue is that is also explodes when the `.` occurs as a decimal point. Is there a way of excluding `decimal` points from the explode function?

My current setup:
As you can see it is exploding at `.` between the two numbers

```
$String = "This is a string.It will split at the previous point and the next one.Here 7.9 is a number";

$NewString = explode('.', $String);

print_r($NewString);

output

Array ( 
[0] => This is a string 
[1] => It will split at the previous point and the next one 
[2] => Here 7 
[3] => 9 is a number 
)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [`preg_split`](http://www.php.net/preg_split) for this with the regex of `/(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)/`:

```
<?php
    $String = "This is a string. It will split at the previous point and the next one. Here 7.9 is a number";

    $NewString = preg_split('/(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)/', $String);

    print_r($NewString);
?>
```

**Output**:

```
Array
(
    [0] => This is a string
    [1] =>  It will split at the previous point and the next one
    [2] =>  Here 7.9 is a number
)
```

[**DEMO**](https://eval.in/61607)

**What does the regex mean?**

- `(?<!\d)` - a "negative lookbehind" meaning it will only match if there is NO digit (`\d`) before the dot
- `\.` - a literal `.` character. It needs to be escaped as `.` in regex means "any character"
- `(?!\d)` - a "negative lookahead" meaning it will only match if there is NO digit (`\d`) after the dot

**Extra:**

You can get rid of the spaces by using a regex as `/(?<!\d)\.(?!\d)\s*/` that will also match any number of white-spaces after the dot, or alternatively you can use `$NewString = array_map('trim', $NewString);`.

Comment: thanks a lot, i didn't think of regex, and thank you for your explanation too.

Answer (score 0):

If need to explode text like in your example, an easy way to do it is to explode ". " instead of ".".

```
$String = "This is a string. It will split at the previous point and the next one. Here 7.9 is a number";

$NewString = explode('. ', $String);

print_r($NewString);

output

Array ( 
[0] => This is a string 
[1] => It will split at the previous point and the next one 
[2] => Here 7.9 is a number
)
```